# Is this Binary Tree Balanced?

Tags: computer-science, trees

I am doing a HW where part ask to build a binary search tree that is unbalanced and part b says if its not balanced then balance it to a AVL tree.

I built the tree with the given array
11, 40, 20, 13, 21, 50, 60, 9, 2, 10

[picture of tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0twz.png)

Part b is where it asks if its unbalanced balance the existing tree that is created in part a. This would indicate that its not balanced but I don't understand why its not already balanced? Is there something obvious I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well an AVL-tree is defined as the left (left half) and the right (right half) subtree not having a height difference of more than $1$, so your tree is indeed balanced yes.

The question, if I read it correctly, asks that *IF* the tree is unbalanced, then balance it. But it isn't unbalanced so you don't have to do anything.